# How to run multiple jQuery effects at same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a box. It is set to hide() in jQuery. It has to fade in, at the same time, it has to move some length from top to bottom. Whatever the length from top to bottom, the fade in effect should begin when the box start moving from top and the fade effect may complete when the box completes it's movement from top.

Here is what I tried;

```
<div id="div1">div</div>
```

and

```
$("#div1").animate({"margin-top": 200,});
$('#div1').fadeIn("slow");
```

But two functions use different time. How can I do this?

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/3C5Xp/)** is the working fiddle.

Comment: You need to add `display: none` to the CSS on your fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing both animations with css in the same `animate` call:

http://jsfiddle.net/xHrBq/

```
$("#div1").animate({
    'margin-top': 300,
    'opacity': 1
}, 1000);
```